# How to expose a function in svelte that can accept parameters to render?

Tags: ecmascript-6, svelte, svelte-3

I'm pretty new to svelte, and for my use case I would like to export the svelte app as a `bundle.js` which exposes a function let's say `startApp(positionInject, appConfiguration)` that can accept 2 parameters (`positionInject` is the app injection position eg: .app, `appConfiguration` is the initial configuration of the app to start), based on those parameters svelte app start renders.

I am wondering, this is possible in svelte?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Svelte component takes a `target` element and `props` as constructor parameters. You can wrap the construction in a function:

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

export function startApp(selector, props) {
  const target = document.querySelector(selector)

  return new App({
    target,
    props
  })
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```js
import {startApp} from "./bundle.js"

startApp(".my-app", {config: ...})
```

Comment: When invoking `startApp('.app', {config:..})` multiple times, it creates another instance of app, would be great if you shed light on how to replace existing app when invoking `startApp` again, Thanks in advance

Comment: Couple of ways to do that:
1) Keep a `Map` of elements to components so you know if it was already loaded
2) Set a flag on the DOM node after you load: `component = new App(...); target.svelteLoaded = true` and then check if `target.svelteLoaded` is set.

Comment: Thanks, Oh I see, I would need to replace the existing app with new one, not checking and stop loading the new one.

Comment: In my use case, svelte app will be in an iframe and new configuration (props) is passed to `startApp` frequently. So I have to replace the existing app with new configuration to `startApp`. Hope you can understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see. In that case you can use `$set()` to update the props of the existing mounted app. See: https://svelte.dev/docs#$set

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for you help. It works perfect for my use case. Do you recommend any course for svelte to get hands dirty in svelte? Thanks again.

Comment: The tutorial at https://svelte.dev/tutorial is really good. I am working on a video course, but no link yet 