# How to create preact multiple embeddable widget?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

How to expose a function that can render a preact app where I can pass render position and props?

There is no webpack config can be edited in preact, so how to achieve this?

I've seen preact-habitat plugin, the widget can't be rendered by passing props to a function.

For my use case I need to create a bundle.js that contains multiple embeddable widgets and preact source.

I can call renderWidgetA(position, props), renderWidgetB(position, props) to render it to position, also I need to pass different props to the existing rendered widget

Is there any way to achieve this?

This is a similar logic with svelte: [How to expose a function in svelte that can accept parameters to render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228891/how-to-expose-a-function-in-svelte-that-can-accept-parameters-to-render)

Highly appreciate for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by position, you mean Mounting HTML element like `body`, `div` or some CSS selector like `'#mountElm'`, then you can export a render function like:

```
import { render, h } from 'preact';

// WidgetA is a Preact component.
// It could be functional or class component.
export function WidgetA(props) {

    // Use props here

    return (
        <div>WidgetA</div>
    );
}


// Render function for WidgetA
export function renderWidgetA(position, props) {

    const renderElm = position instanceof HTMLElement
        ? position
        : document.querySelector(position);

    render(h(Component, props), renderElm);
}
```

When this file is bundled, it can be simply used like:

```
import { renderWidgetA } from './my-bundle.js';

renderWidgetA('body', { title: 'Hello world' });
```

You can follow a similar pattern to create multiple components. Further, you can simply extract the render function into a more generic variant.

#### Question 1: How to make the function available on the global `window` object?

To achieve, this you have two options:

1. Use Webpack and specify `libraryTarget` for the output. It could be `umd` or similar. Read more [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget).
2. If you cannot use Webpack or forbidden from changing it, then at the end of the file, you can explicitly bind it to a global object.

Example:

```
window.myLib = { renderWidgetA };

// Usage
myLib.renderWidgetA('body', { /* some props */});
```

#### Question 2: What to do when a prop changes for a certain widget.

You have to make a change to the `render` function. It accepts the optional [third parameter](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/api-reference#render) that you can set to `true`. So your function becomes:

```
export function renderWidgetA(position, props) {

    const renderElm = position instanceof HTMLElement
        ? position
        : document.querySelector(position);

    // NOTE THE THIRD PARAM
    render(h(Component, props), renderElm, true);
}
```

Once, you do that simply call `renderWidgetA` function whenever your props change. It is completely harmless. Just make sure that your position node remains the same across multiple re-rendering. Also, always remember that **UI as a Function of State**. VDOM will take of everything else for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply. When bundled, will it get registered to the window object for global access? I just want to put the bundle in a script tag and just call `renderWidgetA('body', {a: 1})` anywhere in the document

Comment: One more doubt, When I call renderWidget, it render in a position, If I want to change a props and render it to the same position, what will be the best logic? In svelte we can get a instance of app in return when we initialize with new operator, also there is a $set function to pass different props to existing instance. How can I achieve something similar in preact?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @CaptainAdmin I updated the answer with the questions you asked!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Webpack configuration becomes handy for this purpose but when I see the webpack config of preact-boilerplate it seems outdated, the configuration used uglifyJS instead of terser so I got to know that it was no longer maintained.